# SVG elements in a Html2canvas won't work

Tags: javascript, svg, html2canvas

We know that there are several questions discussing this. However, we have not found anything that works for us. What we originally were looking for was a way to save a div as an image to be able to print it nicely. We then encountered html2canvas, which seemed perfect.

The only problem is that we use SVG elements (lines that connect our objects), and they will not appear in the image. This seams to be an issue for many more people, yet their problems appears to have been solved by the previous update. https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95

We have tried to allow taint to get the SVGs (as suggested [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/103)) but it doesn't work.

We load both html2canvas and html2canvas.svg

```
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="html2canvas.svg.js"></script>
```

This function is called when someone press the "Save to be able to print" button:

```
$(function() { 
$("#btnSave").click(function() {

    html2canvas($("#object_container"), {
        allowTaint: true
    });

    html2canvas($("#object_container"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;

            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=800px, height=800px");

            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                saveAs(blob, "savedImage.jpg"); 
            });
        }
    });

});
});
```

Right now, we do not care about the saved file, only the image that is opened in a new window. In that image we can't see our svg lines.

Any suggestions? (Did we set the allowTaint properly?)

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `allowTaint` in the call with your `onrendered` callback?

Comment: Maybe @Pointy, you mean like: 
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            allowTaint: true

etc..

Comment: No, in the object you pass to the `html2canvas()` function. In other words, in the same (single) call, set *both* `allowTaint` and `onrendered`.

Comment: The latest html2canvas does use promises (.then(callback)). If you do allow the canvas to be tainted you won't be able to call the toDataURL() method. Also, could you make a minimal fiddle that does replicate the issue?